# filefrag fibmap returning wrong physical offset for FAT

Tags: linux, fat, vfat

I am trying to get the map of empty space on any partition in a filesystem-agnostic way. To do this I create a file that uses all of the empty space, then use the 'filefrag -e' command (e2fsprogs v1.42.9) to create a map of the space (on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty, tested with kernels 3.16.0-67 and 4.1.20-040120, dosfstools v3.0.26-1).

This works for most filesystems, but for FAT filesystems specifically I am getting physical offsets beyond the size of the partition.
**Note the problem has now changed, please see the edit below.**

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=temp.img bs=512 count=2048000
$ sudo losetup /dev/loop1 ./temp.img
$ sudo parted /dev/loop1 mklabel msdos
$ sudo parted /dev/loop1 mkpart primary fat32 2048s 1026047s
$ sudo blockdev --rereadpt /dev/loop1
$ sudo mkfs -t vfat /dev/loop1p1
$ sudo mount /dev/loop1p1 ./mnt
$ sudo cp somefile1 ./mnt
$ sudo cp somefile2 ./mnt
$ df -B 512 ./mnt
Filesystem     512B-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop1p1       1023440 21232   1002208   3% ./mnt
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=./mnt/emptyspace.zeros bs=512 count=1002208
$ df -B 512 ./mnt
Filesystem     512B-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop1p1       1023440 1023440         0 100% ./mnt
$ sudo filefrag -b512 -e ./mnt/emptyspace.zeros 
Filesystem type is: 4d44
File size of ./mnt/emptyspace.zeros is 513130496 (1002208 blocks of 512 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0.. 1002207:     348688..   1350895: 1002208:    1350880: merged,eof
./mnt/emptyspace.zeros: 1 extent found
$ cat /proc/mounts
/dev/loop1p1 .../mnt vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,
  iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
$ sudo umount /dev/loop1p1
$ sudo fsck /dev/loop1p1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
/dev/loop1p1: 4 files, 63965/63965 clusters
$ echo $?
0
```

(filefrag returns physical offsets relative to the start of the partition)

```
$ cat /sys/class/block/loop1p1/start 
2048
$ cat /sys/class/block/loop1p1/size
1024000
```

(sysfs start & size are in 512 byte sectors)

Clearly 1350895 is larger than 1024000. Is this a bug in the Linux vfat/fat implementation of the FIBMAP ioctl or is there another reason for this?

I note EmmaV posts a comment alluding to this problem in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161922/view-physical-location-of-a-file-directory-on-a-hard-disk) but there wasn't a definitive answer.

I have also been in touch with Theodore Ts'o (author of filefrag) and he has not indicated a known issue with filefrag.

**EDIT:**
Further to this I have found the above problem is caused by a bug in e2fsprogs v1.42.9. A fix for this is [available here](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/commit/?id=01824c9bbcd2c1037085213f6cd7d591f78db9c5) which is first included in e2fsprogs v1.42.12. I have upgraded and tested and the output is very different.

However, I am still getting a problem with FAT filesystems. The offset is now inside the partition at least, but comparing the content of a file with the blocks returned by filefrag yields a difference. I have written a [python script here](https://github.com/racitup/testfilefrag) for testing. I would be grateful for any feedback and suggestions on what the problem is.

Bonus points goes to the person that can tell me the problem with mkfs for btrfs! :)

Comment: I tried to reproduce it but stays within boundaries for me. What are the mount options according to `/proc/mounts`, and what is the filesystem size according to `df ./emptyspace.zeros`? It's possible for a filesystem to believe it's larger than the device... which version of `filefrag`? Does a Live CD with newer versions give the same results?

Comment: @frostschutz I've added answers to most of your questions in the edit. I'll try the latest kernel version too and report back..

Comment: No idea, sorry; tried to reproduce with your exact device sizes, works for me. Does fsck complain in any way about this filesystem of yours?

Comment: @frostschutz Thanks for your help! Please could you confirm you have followed all steps above and get a different result? If so could you post what results you get and what kernel, filefrag and dosfstools version you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been in touch with OGAWA Hirofumi and Theodore Ts'o and tested various kernels and e2fsprogs tags. The remaining problem is fixed in e2fsprogs v1.43-WIP from 2015 onwards. I believe [this commit](https://github.com/tytso/e2fsprogs/commit/f008143cf5bfb93b5f5a0cb7018091b6f38301f8) fixed the issue.

Full testing history and test script can be [found here](https://github.com/racitup/testfilefrag/wiki).

The moral of the story: don't bother using filefrag for FAT filesystems unless it says `1.43-WIP` and 2015+ at the bottom of the man page.

I should also mention that hdparm --fibmap also has a buggy implementation in v9.43. You'll need at least v9.45 but I haven't thoroughly validated hdparm like filefrag.